# Magento 2: How to get product attributes?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, programmatically

How can I get the list of attributes that a product has?

Foe example: Product "camiseta" has **color** and **size** as available attributes.

[image]

Comment: Where you want to get these attributes?

Comment: In a controller

Comment: Do you want get the value the attributes for one product? or the entity "attribute"?

Comment: I want check if the product has size or color or both as attributes

Answer (score 0):

can you please inject `Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute` check if attributeid is available.

> ```
> /**
>  * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute
>  */
> protected $_eavAttribute;
> /**
>  * @param   Context                                           $context
>  * @param   \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute $eavAttribute
>  */
> public function __construct(
>     Context $context,
>     \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute $eavAttribute
> )
> {
>     $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
>     parent::__construct($context);
> }
> ```

Call the `getIdByCode` method of Attribute in any method

> ```
> $attributeIdcolor = $this->_eavAttribute->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'color');
> $attributeIdsize = $this->_eavAttribute->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'size');
> ```

Comment: please check and let me know it is work :)

Comment: What I need is the list of available attributes for a given product. For example: product camiseta has color and size as available attributes.

Comment: okey i understand. you need each product what are the attribute are available? am i correct?

Comment: What you are asking is written in http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-all-product-attributes-with-name-and-value/

Comment: if i use  $product->getAttributes() i obtain a lot of attributes.  I only need check if has attibutes as in the image